# Why can't I edit the appearance of this editable jComboBox?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jcombobox, renderer

I have this code and MyComboBoxRenderer() seems to not work with it. It has an error in the line with comment written below.

This code is made for autosuggest. So it shows suggestion in a combobox while user types on the textfield.

```
public test2() {
    initComponents();
    
     jComboBox1.setRenderer(new MyComboBoxRenderer1());
     jComboBox1.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
    
    final JTextField textfield = (JTextField)     jComboBox1.getEditor().getEditorComponent(); //it has error in this line
    textfield.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                comboFilter(textfield.getText());
            }
        });
    }
    });
    }
```

Maybe it has something to do with the textfield. My problem is that I wanted to edit the appearance or design of combobox. I want it to inherit the background of the frame. Like transparent. Example are in the pictures.

Here are the pictures. Please click the links below to see it.

[It should be something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spAsA.png)

[Rather than this one. This is the output of the codes above.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cF5ui.png)

And here is the code I have in my combobox renderer.

```
 public MyComboBoxRenderer1(){
    setOpaque(true);
    setFont(new Font ("Segoe UI Semibold", Font.PLAIN ,14));
    setForeground(Color.WHITE);
}


@Override
public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
    setText(value.toString());
   if (isSelected)
    {
      setBackground(Color.WHITE);
      setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    }
    else {
        setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    }
    
    return this;
}
}
```

Why is it that the renderer doesn't work with this? And what should I do to make it work? Can anyone help me please? Thank you in advance. :)

---

EDITED...

I've already set the background transparent. I just need to declare the background of the texfield. XD Yey.
textfield.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
textfield.setForeground(new Color(255,255,255));

But it left small portion that is still not transparent.

I tried doing an additional comboBox on my frame. But it is without the textfield. And it works just fine!

[image: Here it is]

The upper is the comboBox with textfield, the one I have problem with. The lower is the one w/o textfield, I just tried if the code will work with a normal comboBox. I need to make it look like the lower one.

```
     jComboBox1.setRenderer(new MyComboBoxRenderer1());
     jComboBox1.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0)); 
    
     jComboBox2.setRenderer(new MyComboBoxRenderer1());
     jComboBox2.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
```

It has the same code. But it doesn't work with the other one. Maybe it's because of the textfield again?? :(((

Answer (score 0):

```
jComboBox1.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
```

Don't try to use transparent colors. Swing does not know how to paint transparent colors properly. See: [Background With Transparency](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/) for more information.

Instead you change the opaqueness of the component:

```
component.setOpaque( false );
```

In the case of the combo box you need to worry about the component and the renderer, so you might use:

```
comboBox.setOpaque(false);
((JLabel)comboBox.getRenderer()).setOpaque(false);
```

However, this will now cause a problem with the dropdown list. Since the rendering is now transparent you won't see the row selections.

Haven't tested this but a possible solution if to alter the opaqueness of the renderer based on the item being rendered.

The code might be:

```
public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
    JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus)
{
    super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);

    setOpaque(index == -1 ? false : true);

    // add custom painting here

    return this;
}
```

The -1 indicates the item in the combo box is being rendered as oppose to an item in the list.

Comment: setOpaque(index = -1 ? false : true);
this line has error. It says the conditional statement is redundant.

Comment: @RicaJacutina that was a typo. That should be an equality test. The point if for you to understand the concept of the change. If you don't like writing the code as a single statement then change it to an if/else statement.

Comment: @RicaJacutina The code is untested. That was a typo. That should be an equality test. The point is for you to understand the "concept" of the change and make changes as necessary. If you don't like writing the code as a single statement then change it to an if/else statement

Comment: @RicaJacutina glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer. If it didn't help then post a proper [mre] demonstrating the problem.